# Why Anydesk program can not connect? ( Status: result_quit)

Tags: anydesk

I install Anydesk on my pc and I can connect to any devices.
But one device exists that I cannot connect to it.
When I try to connect  to it get the message that:

> The session has ended.
>
> Status: result_quit.

The remote device is connected to the internet currently.
What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the remote device DNS with the DNS provided by the ISP and the problem was solved.