# Cannot connect to pC on AnyDesk, showing "status: result_quit"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, anydesk

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have AnyDesk installed on my laptop. This error occurred suddenly and since then I am unable to connect to the PC (target PC) via AnyDesk.

It is showing "status: result_quit"

The solutions on the web could not solve my problem.

Also, I can connect to other PCs using the AnyDesk on my laptop and also can connect to my laptop using AnyDesk on the target PC. But cannot connect to the Target PC from my laptop.

Please help.

Comment: Does [Why Anydesk program can not connect? ( Status: result\_quit)](https://superuser.com/q/1672109) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill No